# How to make MySQL display duplicate data into my table?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this has something to do with maybe the Primary Key and Unique Keys, but I'm not sure how to how to make it work. Basically I want MySQL to generate a new row even if data in it is duplicate of last rows. Right now, any duplicate data from previous rows result in the row not being generated. Help is very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Check index of every column. If there is unique or primary then just remove it. and add new column id with primary and auto increment.

Comment: if you have primary key (whoch is part of the duplicate data to be inserted) or unique keys just remove them.

Comment: When asking questions of this variety including the cleaned up output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is a hundred times better than a screenshot too tiny to read. It also means people can dump that into sites like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for testing and help you with your answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that go. I'm very new!

Comment: @tadman, sorry for that.

Comment: Another thing you might want to fix before it becomes a problem is to avoid using Latin1 encoding and instead be careful to keep everything UTF-8. It means characters like “ and ™ aren't mangled beyond recognition. If you use `utf8mb4` you can accommodate emoji, too.

Answer (score 0):

The table you have defined has all columns as primary key and unique. It's ideal to maintain one column as primary key (perhaps with auto increment) and the rest as non-indexed columns. Check the table definition with the following mysql query if you are not familiar with using phpMyAdmin

```
desc tablename;
```